# Forward pass gets 10000x slower after iterating for a while

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, pytorch

I implemented a simple Deconv network just like pytorch's official DCGAN tutorial.
I repeatedly pass a `zeros` vector to it. The time taken slows down significantly after a while. I am wondering what the reason is and how I can resolve it.

Code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import time

# JUST TO MEASURE TIME
class Timer:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.process_time()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.process_time()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start

        print('{}: {:.5f}'.format(self.msg, self.interval))

device = torch.device("cuda")

ngf, nc, nz, batchSize = 64, 1, 6, 1<<16
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # input is Z, going into a convolution
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( nz, ngf * 4, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*4) x 4 x 4
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*2) x 8 x 8
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf) x 16 x 16
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
            # state size. (nc) x 32 x 32
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)

# Create the generator
netG = Generator().to(device)

def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)

netG.apply(weights_init)

# torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark=True

while True:
    with Timer('Time elapsed'):
        with torch.no_grad():
            netG(torch.zeros([batchSize, nz, 1, 1], device=device))
```

Result:

> Time elapsed: 0.02309 Time elapsed: 0.00072 Time elapsed: 0.00208 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00128 Time elapsed: 0.00119 Time elapsed: 0.00153 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00176 Time elapsed: 0.00170 Time elapsed: 0.00185 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00188 Time elapsed: 0.00191 Time elapsed: 0.00190 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00171 Time elapsed: 0.00176 Time elapsed: 0.00167 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00120 Time elapsed: 0.00168 Time elapsed: 0.00169 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00166 Time elapsed: 0.00167 Time elapsed: 0.00171 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00168 Time elapsed: 0.00168 Time elapsed: 0.00168 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00169 Time elapsed: 0.00177 Time elapsed: 0.00173 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00176 Time elapsed: 0.00173 Time elapsed: 0.00171 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00168 Time elapsed: 0.00173 Time elapsed: 0.00168 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00178 Time elapsed: 0.00169 Time elapsed: 0.00171 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00168 Time elapsed: 0.00169 Time elapsed: 0.00169 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00173 Time elapsed: 0.00154 Time elapsed: 0.00170 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00167 Time elapsed: 0.00224 Time elapsed: 0.00117 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00175 Time elapsed: 0.00168 Time elapsed: 0.00173 Time
>   elapsed: 0.00169 Time elapsed: 12.62760 Time elapsed: 12.71425 Time
>   elapsed: 12.71379 Time elapsed: 12.71846 Time elapsed: 12.71909 Time
>   elapsed: 12.71898 Time elapsed: 12.72288 Time elapsed: 12.72157 Time
>   elapsed: 12.72226 Time elapsed: 12.72456 Time elapsed: 12.72350 Time
>   elapsed: 12.72480 Time elapsed: 12.72644 Time elapsed: 12.72337 Time
>   elapsed: 12.72424 Time elapsed: 12.72538 Time elapsed: 12.72533 Time
>   elapsed: 12.72510 Time elapsed: 12.72507 Time elapsed: 12.72806 Time
>   elapsed: 12.72865 Time elapsed: 12.72764 Time elapsed: 12.72431

- My GPU: Titan RTX
- PyTorch version: 1.4
- Python version: 3.7

Comment: is this python2.7? You code is probably holding onto to variable that would normally be delete in the back prob, so eventually there is very little memory to work with

Comment: it's python3. if your guess is right, then how should I fix?

Comment: strange I haven't seen `super` in python3. I don't know a lot of pytorch but [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/out-of-memory-error-during-evaluation-but-training-works-fine/12274) might help

Comment: I copied the module from pytorch tutorial and `super` shows no issue with python 3

Comment: Oh yes of course it won't be an issue, you just don't see it often in python3+. Was the link helpful?

Comment: Just fyi I can reproduce this on a TITAN RTX though I'm not completely sure why its happening. I think this is occuring due to the asynchronous behavior of pytorch because if you capture the output via `y = netG(...` then call `torch.cuda.synchronize()` then each iteration takes the same time (about 12 seconds). If you add `torch.cuda.synchronize()` without assigning the output of `netG(...` then it still doesn't wait, but I think that's because there are no variables which are waiting to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the same code on my Titan RTX and got the exact same behavior.

All gpu calls are asynchron (as pointed out by jodag in the comments)and are only synced when needed, if there are dependencies. So to test it I changed the code a bit so the output of the network is actually used and create a dependency such a dependency. So now the output is needed before the next iteration can start.

```py
while True:
    with Timer('Time elapsed'):
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = netG(torch.zeros([batchSize, nz, 1, 1], device=device))
            print(output.mean())
```

Now it takes always 12.8 seconds. So jodag is totally right. It has something to do with the asynchronous calls to the GPU and how pytorch handles everything internally.